# How to reload and animate just one UITableView cell/row?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, animation

how can I reload and animate just one cell/row ?
Right now i download some files. Everytime a file finished downloading, i call it's finished delegate and call [tableview reload].
But then the whole table reloads. And how can i animate the table, so that it doesn't blink in. For example a fade effect or so.

greets Max

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Use the following `UITableView` instance method:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

You have to specify an `NSArray` of `NSIndexPaths` that you want to reload. If you just want to reload. If you only want to reload one cell, then you can supply an `NSArray` that only holds one `NSIndexPath`. For example:

```
NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
[myUITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

You can see the `UITableViewRowAnimation` enum for all the possible ways of animating the row refresh. If you don't want any animation then you can use the value `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`, as in the example.

Reloading specific rows has a greater advantage than simply getting the animation effect that you'd like. You also get a huge performance boost because only the cells that you really need to be reloaded are have their data refreshed, repositioned and redrawn. Depending on the complexity of your cells, there can be quite an overhead each time you refresh a cell, so narrowing down the amount of refreshes you make is a necessary optimization that you should use wherever possible.

Comment: With the new syntax you can also do the following:[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

Comment: @JamesBedford to reload single cell.Do I need to write some in - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method?

Comment: The reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: method is a method of UITableView that you can use to reload a single cell (just pass a single cell index path as an argument!)

Comment: How can I do this from the cell itself? I have a cell view subclass with a button and when I click on the button I want to update the cell from within, instead of having to deal with this in the table view controller. Can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried having the cell have a reference to the table view controller and then just call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on its `tableView`?

Comment: Do i need to reload [myTableView reloadData]   after [myUITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; and cellForRowAtIndexpath called once or array count time?

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4 & 5**

For TableView

```
let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .automatic)
```

For CollectionView

```
let index = IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0)
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [index])
```

Comment: I get the error attempt to insert row 3 into section 0, but there are only 3 rows in section 0 after the update

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to update the text in the tableview cell..

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)_targetMaxDistanceSlider.value];
```

Comment: Thanks this helped with an RTT implementation that didn't need to reload the whole view, but simply the text.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

To reload particular cells in a `tableView` at given `indexPaths`, you need to create an **array** of `indexPaths` and then call function `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` on the `tableView`.

Here is the example:

Swift 5:

```
let indexPathsToReload = [indexPath1, indexPath2, indexPath3]
tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathsToReload, with: .none)
```

Objective C:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = @[indexPath1, indexPath2, indexPath3];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

or

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arraywithobject:@"indexPath1", @"indexPath2", @"indexPath3",nil];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

You can use

```
let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item:0 , section: 0)
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
```

in order to reload a specific cell.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1)
 done it with new syntax

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```