# How to sort the cells to be added either top of the previous cells or bottom of previous cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using AccordionTableView in my swift. Now on each time i added the new accordion cells. The newly added value always comes down the previous values. I need to show them above all the previous values.i am stocked how to do?Can anybody please give me a guide?

Comment: insert the new data to first index of the array, then it will show on first?

Comment: try `yourArrayName.insert(newItem, at: 0)`

Comment: what does new element means?

Comment: `newItem` is your `data` that you inserting to your `tableViewCell` and `reload` your `tableview`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload and animate just one UITableView cell/row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418655/how-to-reload-and-animate-just-one-uitableview-cell-row)

Answer (score 0):

You need to try

```
yourArrayForTableView.insert(data, atIndex: 0)
tableView.beginUpdates() 
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)                                         
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Here new data is added to first row of first section in the tableview.

Comment: this in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

Let someArray be the datasource for your tableView, then you can insert a new row at index 0 like this:

```
someArray.insert(newDataValue, at: 0)
tableView.reloadData()
```