# How do I update a UIButton title in a custom cell from a modal UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a clone of an old app for a friend of mine. One thing in the app is tapping on a "priority" button in a custom cell, it bringing up a picker view, and changing the title of the button to show the priority of the task.
[image]

The picker:
[image]

The picker is in a UIView as a modal. I want to set the picker to the number I want and then dismiss the modal and change the button title to the number I selected in the picker. I have tried all sorts of things and I have not been able to figure out how to do it. It wouldn't be so bad except the button is part of a custom tableview cell. How do I make it do that?

MainListViewController:

```
import UIKit

var defaultCell = "defaultCell"
var itemIndex = 0
var testData: [String] = []
var listItem: [(priorityLevel: Int, itemText: String)] = []

class MainListViewController: UITableViewController, PriorityDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var itemTF = UITextField()
var setIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: defaultCell, for: indexPath) as! ListItemCell
    cell.itemLabel.text = testData[indexPath.row]
    cell.priorityButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(priorityButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    itemIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueID", sender: self)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(75)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard editingStyle == .delete else {return}
    testData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}

@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert title", message: "Message to display", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addTextField { (itemTF) in itemTF.placeholder = "Enter your item" }

    // Create OK button
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        guard let itemText = alertController.textFields?.first?.text else {return}
        self.add(itemText)

    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    // Create Cancel button
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) /* {
        (action:UIAlertAction!) in print("Cancel button tapped"); // Uncomment to make Cancel button do stuff
    } */
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present Dialog message
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

func add(_ newItem: String) {
    testData.insert(newItem, at: 0)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
}

@objc func priorityButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button pressed")
//        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let vc : PriorityViewController = segue.destination as! PriorityViewController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}

func setPriorityLevel(level: Int) {
    print(level)
    // Need to refigure protocol
}
}
```

PriorityViewController (this has the picker) :

```
import UIKit

protocol PriorityDelegate {
func setPriorityLevel(level: Int)
}

class PriorityViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var priorityPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var savePriorityButton: UIButton!

var priorityChosen = ""
var priorityIndex = 0
var delegate : PriorityDelegate?

let priorityLevel = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return priorityLevel.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return priorityLevel[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
//        priorityChosen = priorityLevel[row]
    priorityIndex = row
}

@IBAction func savePriority(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if delegate != nil {
        delegate?.setPriorityLevel(level: priorityIndex)
    }

    dismiss(animated: true)
}
}
```

ListItemCell :

```
import UIKit


class ListItemCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var priorityButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: Easiest way is to just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418655/how-to-reload-and-animate-just-one-uitableview-cell-row

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got it to work! I pieced together a few things from a few different sources and here is what I came up with. I hope this can help someone else because I couldn't find how to do this.

[My GitHub for this project](https://github.com/TimmyWaters/PalmList)