# TableView jumps on top after reloading data. I tried some solutions that I found here, but none of it worked. Please check the description

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am making a chat page, where I scroll on top, I reload the previous message from API. After getting response, reload the table, and the table moves to first cell. But I want it to be stay where it was during loading the messages. Following are the solutions that I tried:

**Solution 1:**
Declared this:
`NSMutableDictionary *cellHeightsDictionary;`

Added this in viewDidLoad:

```
    self.chatTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    cellHeightsDictionary = @{}.mutableCopy;
```

Then added the below mentioned methods:

```
// save height
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cellHeightsDictionary setObject:@(cell.frame.size.height) forKey:indexPath];
}


// give exact height value
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *height = [cellHeightsDictionary objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (height) return height.doubleValue;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

And here reloading my tableview:

```
- (void)reloadAllMessagesHere {
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [self.chatTableView reloadData];
        [self.chatTableView beginUpdates];
        [self.chatTableView endUpdates];
    }];
}
```

***But still the same issue is happening.***

Then I thought I should use the bottom contentOffset of the page. So, I used this method to reload the data:

**Solution 2:**
Removed all above codes and used these methods:
For TableView Height:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

and tableview reload

```
- (void)reloadWithoutMoving {
    CGPoint contentOffsetVal = CGPointMake(0, self.chatTableView.contentSize.height - self.chatTableView.bounds.size.height);
    [self.chatTableView reloadData];
    [self.chatTableView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.chatTableView setContentOffset:contentOffsetVal];
}
```

**BUT NO LUCK!!**

Here check the two images shown below:

**Image 1:** Here I am loading the tableview.

**Image 2:** Here I got the response and the data shown in *Image 1* move to bottom automatically

[image]
[image]

How can I fix this?

[P.S. Please don't mark this as duplicate as I have tried previous the solutions but couldn't fix it.]

Comment: Firstly never set contentoffset. if you donot want scrolling.

Comment: and try only reloadData method of tableview on main queue. without begin update and endupdate

Comment: If I am helping, then you should respond

Comment: Have you removed animation for reloadData and beginupdate and endupdatemethod. And also try with cleaning and delete App way Afterwards.

Comment: if you're only adding one row (or a small number of rows) you shouldn't reload the whole table - have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418655/how-to-reload-and-animate-just-one-uitableview-cell-row

Comment: @Russell : On every API hit I add 20 rows.

Comment: Gautam - then add 20 rows individually, and the table will stay where you have selected

Comment: Have you tried following the answer in the link I sent?  I think that explains it well

Comment: I tried to insert one row, an I got this issue with crash ```'attempt to delete row 21 from section 0 which only contains 20 rows before the update'```